# Create database in console hive without permission in Ranger

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-ranger

I have `not kerberos cluster Hadoop`. I manage the permission hive, hdfs via `Ranger`.
The Resource Path in Ranger for HDFS are:

```
/user/myLogin
/apps/hive/warehouse/mylogin_*
/apps/hive/warehouse
```

I can create a database in hive ( `via console)` also in `Ambari`.
But when I remove the permission `/apps/hive/warehouse` I can't create a database in Hive (Console) but in Ambari I can create it.

This following the error:

```
hive> create database database_tesst;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTa                                                                                                                               sk. MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: 
Permission denied: user=AAAAA, access=EXECUTE, 
inode="/apps/hive/warehouse/database_tesst.db":hdfs:hdfs:d---------
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPe                                                                                                                               rmissionChecker.java:353)
```

How can I create a database or runing a request in hive (console) without the permission `/apps/hive/warehouse` ? Because I should remove this permission from Ranger to allow access users only to there data.

Thank you

Comment: if you do  not manage permission for /apps/hive/warehouse/ from Ranger then HDFS file permissions are applied and it can be noticed that permissions are hdfs:hdfs:d--------- , i.e. no permission for user AAAAA.

Comment: If Kerberos is not enabled, then **anyone can pretend to be a super-user** -- hence Ranger is just a waste of time. Unless super-users are black-listed in Hive (and Ranger). Anyway, try `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs` or `=hive` then start a new Hive session.

Comment: Shubhangi, I manage the permission for /apps/hive/warehouse/ from Ranger

Comment: @Samon Thank you for your answer. Which you mean by a black-list ?